# Help with aluminium capacitor identification

Tags: capacitor, identification

I bought a lenovo i3 mini desktop and it turned up very badly packaged and rattling inside.
I was allowed to keep it so decided to take a look inside and everything appeared fine apart from one capacitor has came off the mainboard.

If this was a normal cap I wouldn't have any problem finding another but I cannot get any clue with the markings on the top. [image: capacitor]

2V100EZA

Comment: Asking for places to buy components is explicitly off-topic here. However, since this is an absolutely standard component, you'll basically be able to buy this at any large electronics distributor for a few cents, so this will not be a challenge.

Comment: What is the barrel diameter ?

Comment: Can you provide a hi-res picture of the mainboard ? If it was ripped off during transport, I would carefully inspect the rest of the mobo for other Damages. If it is indeed rated for 25V it was likely placed near the location, where the power supply connects onto the board. It should be fairly easy to scavenge a suitable replacement from other PCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a high-performance 25V 100\$\mu\$F  Panasonic [EEHZA1E101XP](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDD0000/ABA0000C1221.pdf)  conductive polymer hybrid aluminum electrolytic capacitor with < 30m\$\Omega\$ ESR and 2A ripple current rating.

ZA would be the series

E is the voltage rating (25V)

100 is the capacitance

2V is the lot number

It matches the datasheet markings other than the lot number being on top.

If it matches the 6.3mm\$\phi\$ and 7.7mm height I would be pretty sure of this.

[image]

Comment: ah! Yeah, that is a darn close match!

Answer (score 2):

This reflects none of the marking schemes of KEMET, Panasonic, Würth, Nichicon, so this is a "no name" cap: Probably not very exciting in specs.

**UPDATE**: Spehro's answer correctly points out this is very close to Panasonics' markings, so I'd trust the interpretation in there more than mine!

2V: almost certainly the voltage rating. This is very low, but since this is from modern highly integrated electronics, that might make sense. Higher values are always better, so that's to our advantage.

100: probably the capacity, 100µF

E: seems to be printed differently than "ZA", maybe the binning

ZA: probably the product range.

Since you can't tell dynamic parameters and ESR from any of this, you'd be well-advised to simply buy a "generally pretty good" capacitor that is probably better than the capacitor that became loose. Seeing that this thing is probably just used for decoupling, being a bit lower in ESR will hurt less than being too high.

So, check any inventory of a large distributor, like digikey; click through to the aluminium electrolytic caps, select surface mount ones, select the size that is equal to your capacitor at hand, and look for 100 µF with the lowest ESR you can get in that size.